# creating a reactive JobService

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, android-jobscheduler

I'm creating a `JobService` with Firebase JobDispatcher (very similar to the regular `JobService`) to run in the background and check if data on a server has changed (I can not use push notifications because I don't own the server).

I'm wondering if the `JobService` could be made reactive with the help of a subject: Basically I inject a singleton data repository into my app class that launches the `JobService`, which in turn emits the new data through a subject that can be subscribed to in the app class:

```
@Inject class DataRepo {
     internal val subject = PublishSubject.create<Data>()

     // the service should only be started when there are actually subscribers observing the subject
     val latestData: Observable<Data> = subject
             .doOnSubscribe { jobDispatcher.create(job) }
             .doOnDispose { jobDispatcher.cancel(job.tag) }
             .share()

     val job = JobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()......build()
}

class LoadDataService : JobService() {
    @Inject
    protected lateinit var dataRepo: DataRepo

    private var networkRequest: Disposable? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component.inject(this)
    }

    override fun onStartJob(jobParams: JobParameters): Boolean {
        networkRequest = dataRepo.getNewestData()
                .subscribe({ newData ->
                    dataRepo.subject.onNext(newData)
                    jobFinished(jobParams, false)
                }, { error ->
                    jobFinished(jobParams, true)
                })

        // job hasn't finished yet. Work is still going on in the background
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        networkRequest?.dispose()
        // job was cancelled before jobFinished could be called.
        // The job should be retried if possible
        return true
    }
}

class App {
    @Inject val dataRepo: DataRepo

    override fun onCreate() {
        dataRepo.latestData.subscribe(this::sendNotification)
    }
}
```

the problem is that first of all, my emissions never reach the subscriber in the `App` class, and second there is no guarantee that the device will be awake long enough for all subscribers to finish their work because the system may release the wake-lock after the `JobService` has called `jobFinished()`.